# Transferring a Java class between applications via serialization

Tags: java, serialization

I have successfully serialized *class* Ghost:

```
class Ghost {}

File file = new File("serialized.class.bin");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
oos.writeObject(Ghost.class);
```

Then I'm trying to restore it in a *different* application:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("serialized.class.bin"));
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
Object o = ois.readObject();
```

And I'm getting error the class is missed while (trying) loading it:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Ghost
```

I may not access `Ghost.class` file while deserializing the class. Is it possible to transfer Java classes in a such way?

**UPD**. I assumed class definition (bytecode) is being dumped while serializing a class. I was wrong. The goal is reachable via [getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) although.

Comment: How do you expect the jvm to construct a `Ghost` without the class definition?

Comment: Class definition is in the file. What is the problem to construct it then?

Comment: Its always good practice to provide complete error stack trace.

Comment: @PavelVlasov *"I cannot access Ghost.class file while deserializing the class."* is what I was referring to. Without the class definition, you cant construct an instance of that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the class file in your class path when deserializing the class, since the deserialized format only contains the values of the class non-transient non-static fields.

Comment: The serializing / deserializing facilities are designed to store and restore the state of an object, but not the definition of the class.

Answer (score 5):

Serializing a `Class` object just stores a reference to the class name, it doesn't actually store the class bytecodes (well, it's slightly more complex than that in practice but the effect is the same).  At deserialization time the `ObjectInputStream` will try and load the class by name from its own classloader, so the class needs to be accessible via that classloader already.

Comment: Wha-a-a-at? Serializing a class does not actually serialize the class? That's a useful thing I've learnt today.

Comment: +1. Yes, it serializes only the class descriptor: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/serialized-form.html#java.lang.Class

Comment: @JanDvorak a `Class` object is a kind of runtime "handle" that lets you refer to a class, interrogate the JVM for information about that class's members, create instances of the class, etc.  It's not a representation of the actual `.class` file that defines the class's behaviour, for that you'd need to use something like `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("com/example/Ghost.class")`

Answer (score 0):

When you deserialize a serialized object,  the class of the object has to be on the classpath.

In this context, a `ClassNotFoundException` most likely means that the class required is not on the classpath. You have to address this for deserialization to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to serialize a class, which does not contain any data, because it is a class.
If you want to send a class, send the .class file's bytes and load it with the classloader.
The purpose of Serializing is to convert Objects to bytes and convert it back.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a class for which the class file is not on the class path, you need to use [ClassLoader.defineClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29). The byte array passed as a parameter to that method should contain the contents of the class file (**not** the serialized class object).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transmit a class from one end of a stream to another, you could possibly push the `.class` file itself over the stream, save it to a file, and then use the `ClassLoader` apparatus to load it into the JVM. I have no idea how portable this would be in terms of JVM version etc.