# Java deserialize without knowing class, but knowing interface

Tags: java, serialization, plugins, deserialization, classnotfoundexception

I have a plugin 1 with a Class UserObjects that implements ISharedObjects ans Serializable, which belongs to plugin 2.

Now, my plugin 2 is a framework to synchronize data between clients. in plugin 2, I have a public method setSharedObjects (ISharedObjects object). After that I serialize the data in plugin2 and send it to other clients, that also receive it in plugin 2 and deserialize it.

Now from my design, the framework(plugin 2) should be generic and dont know all implementations of ISharedObject, that other plugins could use. 
So I call in plugin 1 setSharedObjects (UserObjects objects=new UserObjects()).
It is serialized properly, and is transported to other clients. But when they try to deserialize it, they get ClassNotFoundException, because their plugin 2(framework) does not know the Class UserObjects, that lies in plugin 1.
I cannot simply pass the string to plugin 1 and deserialize it there, because it would destroy my whole concept.I also cannot simply import plugin 1 in plugin 2, because I would get loop errors and also my framework should be generic and dont have any informations about the user-plugin (plugin 1 in this case)

Is there any possibility to still make this work? I thought about 2 possible options, but can not het option 1 to run, and have no exact clues to option 2.
Option 1: my plugin 2 defines a SharedObject class, and UserObjects extends SharedObject. then for the transport I cast everything to SharedObject and deserialize it.

Second option: during serialization I store the classloader path of UserObjects in my serialized data, and during deserialization I retrieve this path and it works. But for this solution I have not found, how I can concretely implement it, and would be thankful for any clues.

At the moment I use this serialization function:

```
public String serializeObjectToString(Object object) {
        String encoded=null;        
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream ;
    try {
        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);             
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(object);             
        objectOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    encoded = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));
    return encoded;
    }



public static Object deserializeObjectFromString(String objectString) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {          
    byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(objectString.getBytes());
    Object object = null;
      try {
       ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream( new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes) );
       object = objectInputStream.readObject();
      } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ClassCastException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return object;}
```

If I can realize it with another serialization/deserialization function, than simply tell me with which one.
Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: So my option 1 with an abstract class does not work at all. Maybe third option: when I call plugin 2 from plugin 1, I could register programmatically  the needed classpathes to plugin 2, so that it has the requirde classpathes  by starting deserialization. But I have absolutely no clue how I could do it in Eclipse

Comment: The class to be deserialized must be available in the classpath. Period. The only solution I am aware of is the RMI codebase feature. You could use that without using RMI, by adroit use of the RMIClssLoader, but it's non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is another topic other than "simple or traditionally deserialize" because "simple or traditionally deserialize" not save "class definition". if u do this u will get "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" when deserialize  from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584646/transferring-a-java-class-between-applications-via-serialization)

here is the answer about ["Java deserialize without knowing class, but knowing interface"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258433/how-to-deserialize-an-object-of-unknown-class)
jdeserialize may can do this: https://github.com/unsynchronized/jdeserialize.

> Because of this, it can analyze (serialize) streams without access to
> the class code that generated them.